# Why if one registers on a new SE site can't one comment even with other SE accounts with good reputation?

Tags: discussion

There are many StackExchange (SE) sites now. If one finds one more appropriate to find the answer to a question, but find the accepted answer isn't complete or one needs to add a comment to it, why wouldn't one now be able to (we need 50 reputation)?

If one has enough reputation on other SE sites, one has proven that one can be trusted to make simple actions, even if one has no activity on those new SE sites.

It is my understanding that those other SE sites serve for specialisation grouping of question themes, so why not query other SE sites (such as StackOverflow) to find if one is reputable enough to warrant some minimal reputation?

Comment: Note that this **does** happen - if you have greater than 200 rep on a linked account for any SE site, you get 100 by default on any others. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/creating-accounts

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [a page in the help center](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/creating-accounts),

> Once you’ve earned 200 reputation on at least one Stack Exchange site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.